# C# Windows Form Textbox input to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, hex, windows-forms-designer

I'm very new to C# and have been struggling with an application for days- hopefully someone can help! Sorry if this is a duplicate of a previous question...

I have a Windows Forms programme which allows a user to place hex values in to a textbox which must then be placed in to a byte array and sent via serial to a hardware device.

I have validated my theory by manually initiating a byte array with the correct hex values and confirm that I can get the required response from the hardware. But I can't find a way to add the string values in the textbox directly to the byte array without changing format.

For example I have string: string data = "0x1b, 0x02, 0x43, 0x20, 0xff, 0x1b, 0x03";
And I want to place this data to a byte array: byte[] bytesToSend = { 0x1b, 0x02, 0x43, 0x20, 0xff, 0x1b, 0x03 };

How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
string data = "0x1b, 0x02, 0x43, 0x20, 0xff, 0x1b, 0x03";
byte[] bytes = data.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x.Trim(), 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much! How did you learn this, I am trying to learn C# through practice but haven't yet found a reference manual for me to keep on hand

Comment: I'm happy it helped! I think that time I spent on working with c# made me know this kind of stuff. This Select(...) method is one of the LINQ. You should read about it :D

Comment: Thanks, I have come across LINQ a couple of times but I think I shall take a deeper dive in to understanding this syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for cast string to byte array

```
 var input = textbox.Text;  
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I have tried with the Encoding.ASCII.Getbyes() method previously but always found that when the data was encoded it was no longer accepted by the hardware- it has to be just the raw hex data